# Can't connect anymore to others computers on my local network since I updated to Catalina

Tags: network, catalina

On my local network, there are:

- one Mac Mini running MacOS 10.7.5
- one internet box (Freebox V6) with internal disk, running I don't know what version of custom OS
- one MacBook Air on which I just made the update to MacOS 10.15.4 Catalina

Since that update, I can't connect either to the Mac mini or to the Freebox.
Going thru the Network (⌘ maj K) leads to a 'connection failed':
[image]
For the Freebox, I found a workaround: I can "connect to the server (⌘ K)" using `afp://username:password@192.168.0.254`.
This workaround doesn't work with the Mac mini...

And, by the way, screen sharing from MacBook Air toMac mini works as usual and everything works fine in the other way: the Mac mini can connect to the MacBook Air as it used to do.

Any idea?

Comment: AFP has been deprecated.  Try using SMB instead.

Comment: Maybe, but only another workaround... What about "normal" connect to?

Comment: “Normal” connect to is AFP on Lion.